# Can someone explain to me why arguments within functions immediately get assigned the value of the object at hand?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the code below:

```
// Get Index of object based on id value
var arrayPosition = userListData.map(function (arrayItem) {
  return arrayItem.username;
}).indexOf(thisUserName);
```

Why is it that arrayItem = userListData[0], userListData[1], userListData[2]... ?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean by "Why is it that arrayItem = ..."?

Comment: I don't understand why there are people who down-vote legitimate questions... @plalx [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) loops over userListData, which is an array, with a function. So that function is applied for each array item. What's the first array item? That would be userListData[0]. What's the second? userListData[1], and so on and so forth. Pray somebody vote this back up please. So many people discouraging questions being asked! Just because you don't understand what is asked doesn't mean it isn't a good question...

Comment: Well it has value for me. I found the documentation unclear. Stack Overflow is where you go to verify things. "This question has no value for anyone" is a bit overboard. And if you checked the answer below, you would understand what I was asking about.

Comment: Perhaps everyone has to be an expert before they can ask a question on Stack Overflow, huh. Why is the community filled with so much arrogance?

Comment: You are supposed to do some **research** before posting any question. You said that you did not understand the `map` documentation that you found, but the answer that you accepted is only quoting the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, they do not.

That is just what [the `map` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is designed to do.

> callback — 
>      Function that produces an element of the new Array, taking three arguments:
>
> - currentValue — The current element being processed in the array.
>
> etc

Comment: Holy macaroni man. Thanks for the explanation!!! That explains a lot!